# change of variable: transformation given, find domain of diffeomorphism

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

> Let $D\subset\mathbb R^2$ be given by
>   $$
> y=0,y=x,x+2y=8.\,\,(1)
> $$
>   Let
>   $$
> u=x+2y,v=x-y.
> $$

We can find a diffeomorphism $(u,v)\mapsto T(u,v)=(x,y)$. The diffeomorphism is given by
$$
T(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}1/3u+2/3v\\1/3u-1/3v\end{pmatrix}.
$$
I want to find $D^*$ in the $u,v$-plane such that $T(D^*)=D$. I have drawn the triangle $D$ in the $x,y$-plane, but I’m not sure how to find $D^*$. I tried writing (1) in terms of $u$ and $v$:
$$
\begin{align}
y=0&\implies v=u\\
y=x&\implies v=0\\
x+2y=8&\implies  u=8
\end{align}
$$
The point of this transformation was to compute the integral
$$
\int\int_D\cos(x+2y)\sin(x-y)=\int\int_{D*}3\cos(u)\sin(v),
$$
so I was expecting to find a rectangular $D^*$ in order to make the integral easier with by a change of coordinates. Is my $D^*$ correct, and if so, how should I proceed computing the integral? Could I make use of a symmetric argument, and integrate over $(0,8)^2$, and then divide the integral by 2?

Comment: You can’t turn a triangle into a rectangle with an affine transformation, let alone a linear one. On the other hand, this transformation makes two of the sides parallel to the coordinate axes, which should simplify things.

Comment: @amd I'm sorry, I have no idea what you mean. So should I invoke a second transformation or use this 'parallel property' of the sides, and if so, how?

Comment: Use an appropriate integral theorem to convert it into an integral along the boundary of the region.

Comment: @amd Is it Green's theorem that I have to use? If so, I would have to convert my integrand into the form $\frac{\partial M}{\partial u}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial v}$, but I don’t see how that’s possible with $\cos(u)\sin(v)$

Comment: It’s possible, but messy. In this case, it’s easier to just set up the iterated integral. Since the region is triangular, one of the bounds of the inner integral will be variable, but that should be manageable.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you’ve got the correct Jacobian?

Comment: @amd o right, I had completely forgotten I can put variables in the limits of my integral. That solves the problem. Is there some sort of theorem which talks about this? I have been taught that we are allowed to do this - and that, geometrically, it makes sense - but I've never seen it formally introduced in a calculus book? Also, as far as I can see, the Jacobian is correct, but I guess you have spotted some calculation error.

Comment: I guess in a sense it's still Fubini, but we have to use the fact that for any such set $C$, we have $\int_Cf=\int_Qf_C$, where $Q\supset C$ is a rectangle. yea, I think it's solved. thanks for your help!